# Book recommendation for associative algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory

Currently, I am reading David Radford's Hopf Algebra, and I would like to pick up some representation theory of associative algebras as well since my knowledge of them is pretty shallow at the moment.

Are there any books which gives a good account of associative algebras, and the representation theory of associative algebras?

Comment: Who on earth considers a reference request for representation theory of associate algebras to be too localized?

Answer (score 4):

In addition to Mariano's list:

- Etingof et al.: Introduction to representation theory (which is also available [online](http://www-math.mit.edu/~etingof/replect.pdf)).

Addendum: And one should also mention (although as a starter its speed is too high)

- Benson: Representation and cohomology

Addendum2: One that I haven't read but seems to fit to the question:

- Skowronski, Yamagata: Frobenius algebras

Comment: [Etingof et al.] has a much more all-over-the-place style which is quite great; the other three are more... programmatic :-)

Answer (score 3):

- Pierce's *Associative algebras* is pretty great.
- Auslander, Reiten and Smalø wrote the classic *Representation theory of Artin algebras*
- Assem, Skowroński, Simpson: *Elements of the Representation Theory of Associative Algebras*.

The good first half of any of these and you are pretty much set.

Answer (score 3):

In addition:

C.W.Curtis, I.Reiner, Representation Theory of Finite Groups and Associative Algebras, 2006.

Despite the title, it contains a lot of information on representations of algebras.